# React error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.categories.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

**I'm trying to learn react from  some courses/videos and i got this error couple times and figure it out and solved but right now i can't figure it out. Can someone help me please about this? And also I tried not using "this" but it didn't work
This is the error:
**

```
   Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.categories.map is not a function
    CategoryList.render
    C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Programlar/React-Dersleri/intro/src/CategoryList.js:31
      28 | <div>
      29 |     <h3>{this.props.info.title}</h3>
      30 |     
    > 31 |     <ListGroup>
         | ^  32 |         {
      33 |             this.state.categories.map(category => (
      34 |                 <ListGroupItem active={category.categoryName===this.props.currentCategory?true:false}
    View compiled
    ▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
    (anonymous function)
    C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Programlar/React-Dersleri/intro/src/CategoryList.js:21
      18 |    }
      19 | 
      20 |    getCategories = ()=>{
    > 21 |        fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
         | ^  22 |        .then(response=>response.json())
      23 |        .then(data=>this.setState({categories:data}));;
      24 |    }
```

**here is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navi from './Navi' //bulunduğum klasörden naviiyi import et
import CartSummary from './CartSummary'

import ProductList from './ProductList'
import {ListGroup,ListGroupItem} from 'reactstrap'



export default class CategoryList extends Component {
   
    state = {
        categories: []
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getCategories();
    }

    getCategories = ()=>{
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({categories:data}));;
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.info.title}</h3>
                
                <ListGroup>
                    {
                        this.state.categories.map(category => (
                            <ListGroupItem active={category.categoryName===this.props.currentCategory?true:false}
                            onClick={()=>this.props.changeCategory(category)} 
                            key={category.id}>
                                {category.categoryName}
                            </ListGroupItem>
                        ))

                    }
                    
                </ListGroup>
                { <h4>{this.props.currentCategory}</h4> }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `data` in your `fetch` fulfillment handler is not an array. That's what you have to debug. Look in the Network tab in devtools, or put a breakpoint on the code where you're doing `this.setState({categories:data})`. Whatever JSON your endpoint is returning, it would appear not to just be an array of categories.

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but you're falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun. You need to check for HTTP success before calling `json`, because `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* error, not *HTTP* error. More [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can see that you correctly initialize `categories` with `[]`, we know that the initial state isn't the problem. So we look at the state updates.

The only place you're updating `categories` is here:

```
getCategories = ()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data=>this.setState({categories:data}));;
}
```

So that means `data` in that second `.then` callback isn't an array (because if it were an array, it would have a `map` method).

Two possible reasons for that:

1. Whatever JSON your endpoint is returning isn't just an array of categories. You'll need to look in the Network tab of devtools, or put a breakpoint in that `.then` callback, so see what it actually returns — probably an object with a property that provides the array of categories.
2. You're not seeing the endpoint response at all, but you are still seeing something that can be parsed as JSON. That could be happening because unless the page you're doing this from is on `http://localhost:3000`, you're doing a cross-origin ajax call, which will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless the response contains the necessary [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) headers to allow it. (Your server may also need to handle an `OPTIONS` HTTP call.)

Re #2, you could be missing the fact you're not getting a successful response because your code is falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun: You need to check for HTTP success before calling `json`, because `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* error, not *HTTP* error. More about that [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html), but basically you need to change it to:

```
getCategories = ()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/categories")
    .then(response => {                                       // ***
        if (!response.ok) {                                   // ***
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status); // ***
        }                                                     // ***
        return response.json();                               // ***
     })                                                       // ***
    .then(data => this.setState({categories:data}))
    .catch(error => {                                         // ***
        // Handle/report error.                               // ***
    });                                                       // ***
}
```

The check on `response.ok` is to check for HTTP success. Also note I added a rejection handler. You **always** need to handle rejection, or return the promise chain to something that will. (In this case, you need to handle it; `componentDidMount` won't.)

But again, that alone may not be a fix; I'd say it's likely #1 is the cause, it would be slightly odd if an SOP error happened to be something you could parse as JSON.